# GnuPG -- purpose of individually signing UIDs

Tags: gnupg

Can you please give me a scenario where it would be useful to 
go into the *--edit-key* and sign  *sign* selected user ID
instead of signing all UIDs from command line using *--sign-key*?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the whole point of key signing (aka "certifying") is that you vouch for the binding between the key and the claimed identity.

So there can be situations where you can be certain about someone's personal email, but not their work email. Alternatively, you might want to certify their nickname or callsign, but not necessarily their legal name. Or the other way around.

(Besides: UIDs can be added at any time later, not just when creating the key. Sometimes you might want to sign just the new ones, or just old ones.)